# awk - command how to handle when file has no records

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have awk command which compares two csv files and if a records is found appends the files with values from one file and creates a new file .which works fine and gives expected output when both the files have records. but when one of the file is empty not getting the desired result. how to handle the empty file and get the required output

The script which i have is

```
    #!/bin/ksh
set -x
#dos2unix $SCRIPT_HOME/input/declined/file1.csv $SCRIPT_HOME/input/declined/file1.csv
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==NR {a[$2]=$1 ;b[$15]=$15;c[17]=substr($17,1,1);next;}
{
print $12;
if($12 in b){
print $0,a[$17],c[17];
}

else {
{print $0}}

}' $SCRIPT_HOME/input/declined/declined.csv $SCRIPT_HOME/input/declined/file2.csv >  $SCRIPT_HOME/input/error/file2.csv
```

In my case when the file declined.csv is empty i just want to print out the file2.csv records as it is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used the option `[ ! -s $SCRIPT_HOME/input/declined/declined.csv ] ||`
to verify file is empty or not.

```
[ ! -s $SCRIPT_HOME/input/declined/declined.csv ] ||
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==NR {a[$2]=$1 ;b[$15]=$15;c[17]=substr($17,1,1);next;}
{
print $12;
if($12 in b){
print $0,a[$17],c[17];
}

else {
{print $0}}
}' $SCRIPT_HOME/input/declined/declined.csv $SCRIPT_HOME/input/declined/file2.csv >  $SCRIPT_HOME/input/error/filea2.csv

[ -s $SCRIPT_HOME/input/declined/declined.csv ] ||
{
print " i am here executing";
cp $SCRIPT_HOME/input/declined/file2.csv $SCRIPT_HOME/input/error/file2.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
FNR==NR
```

to:

```
FILENAME==ARGV[1]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. i will try it but before i could read your suggestion I found another way to handle the situation i.e using [-s filename] option

Comment: That's just silly. Why add more logic to your shell script when simply tweaking the condition in your awk script will handle it?